# Android - CircularImageView setImageDrawable with programmatically created drawable

Tags: java, android

I want to create icons similary to the google contact app.
I wish to provide a background color and a text and generate the icon.

[image]

What I'm trying at the moment is something like the solution [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9832777/programmatically-creating-icon-to-use-as-itemizedoverlay-drawable-android)
I'm using the [CircularImageView external library](https://github.com/Pkmmte/CircularImageView) and it seems to be the problem. In fact if I try to do:

```
CircularImageView imageView;
....
Drawable d = new TextDrawable("My Text", mycolor, textSize);
imageView.setImageDrawable(d);
```

I get this error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
>   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:829)
>        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:808)
>        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:775)
>        at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.drawableToBitmap(CircularImageView.java:327)

while if I use the standard **ImageView** it works. Any advice?

Comment: TextDrawable? Is this a library if so which one?

Comment: Please mark which line of code throws the exception and maybe add some more... That's too little information

Comment: No it's the name used in the answer I mentioned [here you can see](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34643277/android-imageview-setimagedrawable-with-programmatically-created-drawable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you see is because the library you are using does not account for drawables without fixed dimensions.

You can see [here](https://github.com/Pkmmte/CircularImageView/blob/aca59f32d9267c943eb6c930bdaed59c417a4d16/circularimageview/src/main/java/com/pkmmte/view/CircularImageView.java#L401) that it uses the drawable intrinsic height and width, which both default to `-1` to suggest that the drawable will just fill any sized bitmap.

To fix your problem you would just need to override `getIntrinsicHeight()` in `TextDrawable` to return values > 0.

```
@Override
public int getIntrinsicHeight() {
    return 88;
}

@Override
public int getIntrinsicWidth() {
    return 88;
}
```

This would suggest your drawable to be a size of 88x88px. To further improve this you would need to supply dp -> px values, so that your drawables don't get stretched on higher resolution devices or squeezed on low dpi ones.

Answer (score 2):

I've already found on GitHub a library, which makes your desired effect:

> ### TextDrawable
>
> This light-weight library provides images with letter/text like the Gmail app. It extends the `Drawable` class thus can be used with existing/custom/network `ImageView` classes. Also included is a [fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) for creating drawables and a customizable `ColorGenerator`.
>
> [image][image]
>
> https://github.com/amulyakhare/TextDrawable

As you wish to create your own implementation, try to read carefully code of this library and step-after-step implement your own version

Hope it help

Comment: if you feel it's good answer for your question please mark this post. It would help people with similar problem ;-)